# Removing Attributes using Html Agility Pack

Tags: html, parsing, html-agility-pack

When I run this code, the .RemoveAll method is fired:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var elementsWithAttribute = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@*");
if (elementsWithAttribute != null)
{
    foreach (var element in elementsWithAttribute)
    {
        element.Attributes.RemoveAll();
    }
}
```

But the `doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` still contains tags with attributes. (I have tried flushing the doc to a string via the save method and a memory stream, but the result is the same).

How can I remove all attributes from all tags (but keep the tags)?

Comment: It's interesting that if I re-run the loop (using debug mode) after running it once, the select returns 0 rows, indicating that the remove has 'taken effect' - but I can't see the result in the html representation!

Comment: What happens if you run a similar `foreach` for `doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml`?

Comment: OuterHtml is a string - I don't think I can iterate that in the same way, right?

Comment: Perhaps that's why the attributes aren't removed from OuterHtml.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding? I thought the `doc.DocumentNodeOuterHtml` would be a string representation of the document that I have altered via the api calls

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/34366

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly my problem. I had a debug watch on the property which was causing it to evaluate -  just once! If you add as an answer, I'd gladly award the points!